# Deploying minified versions JS/CSS using Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, minify

I'm a kind of big rookie, using Netbeans 6.9 as a PHP dev tool.

Currently I do develop and test locally on my PC using XAMPP/Apache/MySQL and once done, use Netbeans "upload" facility to the production server on the web.

I was wondering if there's a Netbeans tool capable of minifying js/CSS files on upload, or a tool to minify the whole "production" environement, on request.

Comment: This might be a late comment, but this question appears on top search result.Therefore, I have a question. If you have tried the plugin, can you manage to change the output directory ?

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't tried.

Comment: it's ok, thanks. This plug in needs to be updated to allow more customization such as change the build directory path and name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Netbeans JS CSS Minify Plugin :  [Download From Here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49666/js-css-minify-compress)

Comment: Break url. Is'nt  working.

Comment: Is there an alternate location for this plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Not integrated with Netbeans but will do the trick for what you want: http://code.google.com/p/minify/

Comment: I personally prefer the YUI Compressor (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).  Same thing though :D

Comment: Is there a best practice to minify only the "production" website?

Comment: In terms of best practice, "minify" your code before you put it into production is really only suggestion I can make.  

My suggestion is to write a script to minify your code when you are ready to push to production.

Comment: If you have numerous scripts, it'd be good to combine them into a single script so the browser is making a single HTTP request instead of a dozen requests.  The file will be larger, but if it's minified, it shouldn't be terrible.  I hate Wordpress blogs that have 22 JS files and 30 CSS files.

Comment: Nathan, same here. I'm looking at W3 Total cache, seems quite nice doing a part of the job. Needs tuning and some drawbacks: it looks like it can cache and minify external JS (according to YSlow I have 26... ARRRGGHHH!!!), however you will have to continuously check for updated versions of cached JS....

Comment: It take some management but there are benefits.  Make it work.

Answer (score -1):

I usually write a deployment script that does all these things for me: It copies the current development version to a deployment folder, filtering out files I don't need, generating the correct settings files, and a bunch of other deployment-related tasks. The result is a folder that matches the folder structure on the web server exactly; from there, all I need to do is upload everything. On *nix systems, this is even more powerful because pretty much everything is designed to be scriptable.
If you adopt such a scheme, all you need is a scriptable minifier, add it to the deployment script and you're all set.

Comment: At the moment Netbeans itself is capable to mantain the same structure on the production server in such a way, once a source file is ready to be deployed, I just force "upload" and Netbeans will do the rest, storing the source file accordingly in the proper folder on the production server....